# How to install OS X 10.12 command line tools on 10.11?

Tags: macos, homebrew, geckodriver

I get this error when trying to `brew install geckodriver`

```
==> Installing geckodriver dependency: rust
==> Downloading https://static.rust-lang.org/dist/rustc-1.42.0-src.tar.gz
######################################################################## 100.0%
==> ./configure --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/rust/1.42.0 --release-channel=stable
==> make
Last 15 lines from /Users/nilshaus/Library/Logs/Homebrew/rust/02.make:
2020-04-12 21:13:48 -0400

make

make: error: unable to find utility "make", not a developer tool or in PATH
xcodebuild: error: SDK "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.12.sdk" cannot be located.
clang: error: unable to find utility "clang", not a developer tool or in PATH

Do not report this issue to Homebrew/brew or Homebrew/core!

These open issues may also help:
Rust dependents that currently fail to build from source https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/issues/50815

Error: You are using macOS 10.11.
We (and Apple) do not provide support for this old version.
You will encounter build failures with some formulae.
Please create pull requests instead of asking for help on Homebrew's GitHub,
Discourse, Twitter or IRC. You are responsible for resolving any issues you
experience while you are running this old version.
```

Obviously 10.11 is no longer supported by Homebrew. The fact that it can't find `make` is weird, but I'm willing to bet that the real issue is that the rust build expects the 10.12 command line tools. Is there a way for me to install them on OS X 10.11? I have Xcode 8.

Comment: Have you solved this problem?

Answer (score 1):

I encountered this same error message when `brew upgrade` installed a new version of clang and tcl-tk. Found a workaround here:

> Xcode was overriding the command line tools install. After moving
> Xcode to the trash I found the directory of the command line tools
> install:

**clang --version**

`/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin`

`/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin`

https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/1139#issuecomment-302967251

---

**Another possible workaround** - instead of moving Xcode, choose one of the following to specify CLT version:

`sudo xcode-select -s /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools`

`sudo xcode-select -s /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer`

To display the current CLT path: `xcode-select -p`
https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/1139#issuecomment-303033942

Comment: Using `xcode-select` to make the CLT is the correct answer. On some older systems, formulae that set SDKROOT fail to build if Xcode is active. This was fixed in macOS 10.13, such that `SDKROOT=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk xcrun -show-sdk-path` no longer fails.